# WoeUSB creating bootable USB not working

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, woeUsb, 15 GB usb3 Stick, windows 10 64Bit ISO to create bootable device. I found few tutorials how to do it, but I still get error.

- Installation failed!
- Exit code: 256

Log:

> WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
>   ============================== Mounting source filesystem... Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sda...
>   wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing initialization failed: No medium
>   found The command "wipefs --all "${target_device}"" failed with exit
>   status "1", program is prematurely aborted Unmounting and removing
>   "/media/woeusb_source_1532252869_8362"... You may now safely detach
>   the target device

I tried to format my USB several times but nothing worked. I used FAT32 format. Should I first convert it to NTFS?

Answer (score 20):

I have the same issue and found the solution by unmounting USB drive in this way,

Go to the Disks and select your USB drive from the left side menu, and click on the icon shown in the below image to unmount USB.[image]

Comment: This works, unmounting via the title bar symbol screws it up somehow

Comment: Unfortunately it does seem like unmounting from Dolphin has the same problem. However, I found out this works (for me, anyway) if I just `sudo umount /dev/sdXX` from the command line, where sdXX is something like /dev/sdc1.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had ejected the drive through the file explorer before. I had to reinsert it and then unmount them using `Disks` or the command line.

Comment: Can confirm unmounting this way makes everything work. Weird.

Answer (score 9):

The command line version of the tool works better in my experience:

```
woeusb --device Win10_1909_English_x64.iso /dev/sdX --target-filesystem NTFS
```

`/dev/sdX` might be different on your system such as sda sdb ..., make sure to check the device path using `gparted` or `fdisk`.

Make sure to set the filesystem to NTFS with `--target-filesystem NTFS` as FAT32 doesn't support large files.

Comment: Indeed the command line option works way better! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to run the software with sudo because it requires the use of gparted. If you don't do this it won't succeed and exit. I suspect this is your problem. I had a similar problem.

Comment: WoeUSB doesn't required gparted, it requires parted.

Comment: it also prompts for de sudo password when you press install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after surfing internet I found something like this: **

> sudo woeusb --device image.iso  /dev/sdb --tgt-fs NTFS --verbose

**. So in the command image.iso is the OS you downloaded(or the path to it), while the /dev... is the USB device and type of format(NTFS). Just copy the command, change image.iso to the path of your image.iso and change the /dev/sdb to the name of your USB device and make sure you are connected to internet because when I ran the command it seems it communicated with GitHub. Good luck I hope this will help if you haven't found any answer.

Answer (score -4):

There is no need to use any third party tool in the Windows operating system to create a bootable USB. Follow the below commands:
 1. Plug your USB drive
 2. Open Command Prompt
 3. Type: diskpart . 
 4. Type list volume (this will show your drives)
 5. Type sel vol h (h can be replaced with ur usb volume, can be anything g, h, i)
 6. Type active
 7. It will make your USB active, copy and paste windows files inside it.

Comment: The question is about using WoeUSB in the Ubuntu operating system, not in windows.